# Decision Tree Learning

Tags: python, decision-tree

I want to implement the decision-tree learning alogorithm.

I am pretty new to coding so I know it's not the best code, but I just want it to work. Unfortunately i get the error: `e2 = b(pk2/(pk2 + nk2))
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see the line `e2 = b(pk2/(pk2 + nk2))`in your code snippet, but I think the Error is quite expressive: You divide by zero, which is mathematical undefined. Since you divide `(pk2 + nk2)`, could it be that these to can be the same with different sign?

Comment: Can you share the code of `count` method

Comment: Yes, i have added it now! I know you can't divide by zero, but i don't understand where the zero comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume after some splits you are left with two records with 3 features/attributes (last column being the truth label)

`1   1   1   2
2   2   2    1`

Now you are about to select the next best feature to split on, so you call this method `remainder(examples, attribute)` as part of selection which internally calls `nk1, pk1 = pk_nk(1, examples, attribute)`.

The value returned by `pk_nk` for the above mentioned rows and features will be `0, 0` which will result in divide by zero exception for `e1 = b(pk1/(pk1 + nk1))`. This is a valid scenario based on how you coded the DT and you should be handling the case.

Answer (score 0):

`(pk2 + nk2)` at some point equals zero. If we step backwards through your code, we see they are assigned here:

```
nk2, pk2 = pk_nk(2, examples, attribute)
```

```
def pk_nk(path, examples, attribute):
    nk = 0
    pk = 0
    for ex in examples:
        if ex[attribute] == path and ex[7] == NO:
            nk += 1
        elif ex[attribute] == path and ex[7] == YES:
            pk += 1
    return nk, pk
```

As such, for the divisor to equal zero `nk` and `pk` must remain zero through the function, i.e. either:

- `examples` is empty, or
- neither if/elif condition is satisfied

Comment: @AtleVågenSvendsgaard well, that depends on what you want the code to do. If the code is written as expected, then you have a problem with your input. If not, you need to change the logic to accommodate those input values. But I can't tell you what should/shouldn't be valid input.